# autoconf - how to check for a (minimal) version of a library at configure time?

Tags: configure, autoconf

I want to add a check for a minimal version of a library that I need for my project at configure time.

The library itself stores its version in a struct `library_name_version_struct`, such that I could obtain the library version using the following code:

```
#include "library_name.h"

void main(void){
  printf("%s\n", library_name_version_struct.version);
}
```

which would give me the output

```
libraryMAJOR.MINOR.MICRO
```

I thought of trying to get autoconf to run that minimal code, capture the output, and then (at least as a start) just stupidly check whether the output string is in a list of permissible output strings that I specify. Something along the lines of

```
AC_MAGIC_COMMAND_THAT_I_DONT_KNOW( [[#include "library_name.h"], 
                              [printf("%s\n", library_name_version_struct.version);]],
                              [STORE_OUTPUT_IN_THIS_VARIABLE],
                              [Oh no something went really wrong])

case STORE_OUTPUT_IN_THIS_VARIABLE in
  library_name1.0.0 | library_name1.1.0 | (etc...) | library_name3.1.0)
     # we good
  ;;
  *)
     AC_MSG_ERROR([STORE_OUTPUT_IN_THIS_VARIABLE is not a permitted version])
  ;;
esac
```

Any other or better way of achieving this would also be very much appreciated. I just want to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

The Autoconf macro you are looking for is `AC_RUN_IFELSE`.

```
AC_RUN_IFELSE([dnl
AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
]], [[
  const char *known_good[] = {
    "library_name1.0.0",
    "library_name1.1.0",
    ...
    "library_name3.1.0",
    NULL
  }; 
  const char *version_string = library_name_version_struct.version;
  for (size_t i=0; known_good[i] != NULL; ++i) {
    if (strcmp(known_good[i], version_string) == 0) {
      return 0; /* we good */
    }
  }  
  return 1; /* we not good */
]])
], [dnl
  AC_MSG_RESULT([yesss])
], [dnl
  AC_MSG_RESULT([noooo])
  AC_MSG_ERROR([cross-compiling, library_name not found, error compiling with or linking against library_name, or unsupported library_name version])
])
```

However, there are at least two problems with using `AC_RUN_IFELSE` to check for the runtime value of `library_name_version_struct.version`:

- `AC_RUN_IFELSE` cannot detect the library version when cross compiling.
- The library version present at the time your binary program is built can differ from the library version the compiled program eventually runs with.

I would try to look for a different mechanism to check for the library version. Check for some minimum ABI version for compilation (e.g. with `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` if the library in question supports that), and then maybe an actual runtime check for inside the compiled program.

More details about or a concrete pointer to the library in question might enable a more useful answers.

Comment: I found AC_RUN_IFELSE, but I didn't see the option to grab output of the compiled and run program and return it as a variable into the configure script for later use.